# CursorLoader does not refresh if notifyChange() is called before CursorLoader registers ContentObserver

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-loadermanager, android-cursorloader

I have a `CursorLoader` that loads data from local `SQLite` database.

The data in `SQLite` is actually a cached copy of a remote `API` response, so I start an asynchronous refresh of `SQLite` data whenever it is queried by the `CursorLoader`.

Following is the sequence of steps I follow to respond to the data query in my `ContentProvider`:

1. Query `SQLite` for `cached data. cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri)` is called on the returned cursor.
2. Start an asynchronous call to remote `API`. Once the response is received, `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null)` is called.
3. Sleep for `5` seconds to cause a delay in receipt of cursor by the `CursorLoader`. (This is done to easily reproduce my problem).
4. Return the cursor obtained in `Step 1` to the `CursorLoader`.

In the less likely but possible scenario of the asynchronous remote `API` call completing (and `notifyChange()` being called) before  the `CursorLoader` could register a `ContentObserver` on the obtained cursor by calling `registerContentObserver(cursor, mObserver)` [ see http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/content/CursorLoader.java#CursorLoader.loadInBackground%28%29 ], the data change notification is missed by the `CursorLoader` and therefore the `Activity` does not see updated data.

I can get around this problem by writing my `LoaderCallBacks` such that the data is loaded twice - first only cached data is loaded and then a `refresh` request is made. This way the `CursorLoader` gets to register `ContentObserver` before the `refresh` call starts.

However, this is something that should ideally be handled by the `CursorLoader` itself, as `CursorLoader` advertises automatic update of the cursor. Doing it in every `Activity` causes a lot of bloat in `Activity` code.

Comment: @diosney Thanks for the formatting! Will keep this in mind in future.

Comment: You're welcome! We are here to help each other :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach is to register the observer before starting with the loading of the cursor. You need to register for the Uri instead of for the cursor.

```
 getActivity().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
 your_Uri, true,
 new YourObserver(mHandler));

getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

Comment: From docs it seems that the CursorLoader it's already refreshing content and you don't need to use a ContentObserver. Actually I can't make it automatically refresh on changes but I'll update it as soon as I solve this issue.

Comment: Ok with CursorLoader you don't need to add a ContentObserver. You just need to add in your ContentProvider's query method, just before returning the cursor this: cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri). This will do the trick

Comment: @StErMi - that's incorrect if you are loading a 'derived' URI, for example a view. In that case you DO need to add another ContentObserver so that your Cursor (backed by a view) is notified when one of the underlying tables (with it's own Uri) changes.

Comment: @zyamys It's ContentProvider's job to tell the resolver which URIs should be notified. Situation described should not happen if content provider is implemented properly.

Comment: @Pius - good point, assuming you have control over the provider that's a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

get a reference to your loader while initializing as follows

```
Loader dayWeatherLoader = getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_DAY_WEATHER, null, this);
```

then create a class that extends ContentObserver as follows

```
class DataObserver extends ContentObserver {

public DataObserver(Handler handler) {
    super(handler);
}

@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
    dayWeatherLoader.forceLoad();
}
}
```

Then register content observer inside onResume lifecycle method as follows

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();
getContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(CONTENTPROVIDERURI,true,new DayWeatherDataObserver(new Handler()));
}
```

Whenever there is a change in the underlying data of content provider, the onChange method of contentobserver will be called where you can ask loader to load the data again